# Which Account is being used by Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

I am trying to use a Sandbox Tester Account on my Mac to test In-App purchases with the *Mac App Store*. From Apple's documentation it seems I need to sign into my Sandbox Tester account on my Mac to test this functionality.

I have a few developer accounts, in addition to a sandbox tester account, in Xcode. How can I determine (and change) which account Xcode uses when my app queries Apple with the *SKProductsRequest* API?

I am running the app directly from Xcode.

Comment: Have you tried logging in with the tester account in the Mac App Store app?

Comment: @LeoNatan yes I have, I am successfully logged into the tester account

Comment: So `SKProductsRequest` will use that account.

Comment: Thanks, that worked !

Answer (score 1):

As @LeoNatan pointed out, just sign into the Mac Developer account with the Sandbox Tester account. This will be enough -- the app will then use that account for communication via *SKProductsRequest*